# Evaluate a number to numbers in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, difference

I am making a random number generator to assign tasks. I want to give everyone a random number then generate the random number. I then want to list the people in order of how close they were.

I thought maybe to iterate through the array and find the absolute difference between the `winningNumber` and the numbers in the way. However, I'm not sure how to link the numbers back to the name in the list.

How can I evaluate these numbers?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/z0xvq6oy/)

HTML:

## Random Number Assigner

```
<p>Have tasks to assign but no volunteers? Sign them up here</p>
<div id="input-area">
<input type="text" placeholder="Lucky person here" id="input">
<button id="button">Add Them!</button>
<br>
<br>
<button id="random">Generate Random Number</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="list-area">
<ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#input-area {
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function randomNumber() {
return Math.round((Math.random()) * 100);
};
var randomNumberValue;
var winningNumber;
var myArray = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log("The JavaScript has loaded");
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    randomNumberValue = randomNumber();
    var inputValue = $('#input').val();
    if (inputValue === "") {
        return;
    };
    $('#list').append("<ul>" + inputValue + ": " + randomNumberValue + "             </ul>");
    myArray.push(randomNumberValue);
    $('#input').val("");
});
$('#random').on('click', function () {
    myArray.sort();
    winningNumber = randomNumber();
    if (winningNumber === 0) {
        winningNumber++;
    };
    console.log(myArray);
    console.log("The winning number is: " + winningNumber);
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        i - winningNumber;
    };
    console.log(myArray);
});
});
```

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly ? What is expected result ?

Comment: You need to store the name with their number in a JSON object. Calculate the distance, and then use a package like [lodash](https://lodash.com) to pick the closest person.

Comment: I thought about putting it into an object, JSON could work, but then thought maybe there is an easier way and I should ask. That seems relatively long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some small adaptions:

```
function randomNumber() {
  return Math.round((Math.random()) * 100);
};
var randomNumberValue;
var winningNumber;
var myArray = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("The JavaScript has loaded");
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        var randomNumberValue = randomNumber();
        var inputValue = $('#input').val();
        if (inputValue === "") {
            return;
        };
        // an item in a list is the <li> element
        $('#list').append("<li>" + inputValue + ": " + randomNumberValue     + " </li>");
        // to simplify things I've used normal arrays for storage
        // instead of a list of {key:value} pairs
        // Advantage of {key:value} pairs here would be an easier check for multiple name entries
        myArray.push([randomNumberValue,inputValue]);
        $('#input').val("");
    });
    $('#random').on('click', function () {
        // not needed in this simple algorithm
        // You can use a binary search if the array is sorted which would make it faster
        // but also much more complicated and isn't worth the hassle for small lists
        //myArray.sort();
        var winningNumber = randomNumber();
        // get the first number for a start (numbering starts at zero)
        var current = myArray[0][0];
        // we need something to keep the position of the entry
        var pos = 0;
        console.log("The winning number is: " + winningNumber);
        for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            // the actual number at position i in the array
            var value = myArray[i][0];
            /*
                  Compute two differences
                  a) between the drawn number and the actual number
                  b) between the drawn number and the last number that was
                     nearest to the last actual number

                  If the actual difference a is smaller than the last difference
                  it is better, hence we keep it. We have to know where it was to
                  be able to name the winner and keep the position to do so.
             */ 
            if(Math.abs(winningNumber - value) < Math.abs(winningNumber - current)){
                current = value;
                pos = i;
            }
            // No "else" here because, well, we don't need to do anything, just go on
            // until something is found.
        };
        console.log("The winner is: " + myArray[pos][1]);
        console.log(myArray.join(" | "));
    });
});
```

One caveat: you do not check for double entries. Both, the name and the random number can repeat and need to be checked, otherwise it may fail in curious ways.

Comment: This solves the problem well but do you mind explaining what's going on inside of the `for` loop? I see that it's got the `var value` which is an array with two properties. It then uses an `if statement` to position the elements in the array? Shouldn't `myArray[pos][1]` be checking for the 0 position?